# Reusing calculated column in update in same code-block

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the (best) way to update column of table based on calculated another column.
First of all, I am using function to calculate value for 'BAS_CBR_EB_RWA' column and then I am using 'BAS_CBR_EB_RWA' value as an input for 'BAS_CBR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL' column calculation, as shown in below-mentioned code.

Could you please share how to reuse it to do next calculation. replacing 'BAS_CBR_EB_RWA' with right-hand calculation isn't desirable because we have too many calculation of this type and it'll confuse other users.

Thanks in advance for help.

```
IF INSTTABLE = 16 THEN
  UPDATE LAO_DATA
    SET BAS_CBR_EB_RWA =  BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD,
                                        CBR_CUR_BOOK_BAL,
                                        BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K,
                                        V_BASEL_MIN,
                                        V_BAS_RWA_RATE),
        BAS_CBR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL  = ROUND(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(V_DATE, 
                                                            BAS_CBR_EB_RWA,
                                                            0),
                                          2),
    WHERE (AS_OF_DATE = V_DATE);

    --COMMIT;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can update a subquery.  I'm not 100% sure if it works for UDFs, but you can try:

```
UPDATE (SELECT LD.*,
               BAS2_RWA_CALC(BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD, CBR_CUR_BOOK_BAL, BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K, V_BASEL_MIN, V_BAS_RWA_RATE) as new_BAS_CBR_EB_RWA
        FROM LAO_DATA LD
       )
    SET BAS_CBR_EB_RWA = new_BAS_CBR_EB_RWA,
        BAS_CBR_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = ROUND(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(V_DATE, nw_BAS_CBR_EB_RWA, 0), 2),
WHERE AS_OF_DATE = V_DATE;
```

Answer (score 2):

A `MERGE` statement can be used. You may also replace `ROWID` with the primary key or a Unique key of the table.

Put all your first level of calculations with function calls inside the `USING()` block and the second level of calculation for RHS in the `SET` expression

```
MERGE INTO lao_data t
USING (
           SELECT ROWID AS rid,bas2_rwa_calc(bas_capital_calc_cd,
                    cbr_cur_book_bal,
                    bas_cap_factor_k,
                    v_basel_min,v_bas_rwa_rate
           ) AS new_BAS_CBR_EB_RWA
           FROM lao_data
           WHERE as_of_date = V_DATE
      )
s ON ( s.rid = t.rowid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET t.bas_cbr_eb_rwa = s.new_BAS_CBR_EB_RWA 
    t.bas_cbr_eb_total_capital 
                     = round(bas2_mgrl_capital(v_date,s.nw_BAS_CBR_EB_RWA,0), 2) );
```